# How to take a user sentence and create a list of words out of it?

Tags: python, list

I'm unsure what the user will enter but I want to break their input sentence up into words in a list

```
User_input = raw_input("Please enter a search criterion: ")
User_Input_list[""]

# input example: steve at the office

# compiling the regular expression:
keyword = re.compile(r"\b[aA-zZ]\b")
     for word in User_input:
         User_Input_list.append(word?)

# going by thin put example input I'd want
# User_Input_list["steve", "at" , "the" , "office"]
```

I'm unsure how to split the input up into separate words? I will give cookies for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
User_Input_list = User_input.split()
```

Comment: It will work with any kind of string and split on whitespace characters, the same way `word in string` does it.

Comment: @Ryan This will work on any string as will the solution from @oleide and the others. The difference between oleide's solution and mine is that my solution splits on any whitespace whereas his only splits on the ' ' (space) character. Either approach can be useful for different situations.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is probably to use `split`:

```
>>> "steve at the office".split()
['steve', 'at', 'the', 'office']
```

But this won't remove punctuation, which may or may not be a problem for you:

```
>>> "steve at the office.".split()
['steve', 'at', 'the', 'office.']
```

You could use `re.split()` to only pluck out letters:

```
>>> re.split('\W+', 'steve at the office.')
['steve', 'at', 'the', 'office', '']
```

But as you can see above you might end up with empty entries to deal with, and things worse when you have more subtle punctuation:

```
>>> re.split("\W+", "steve isn't at the office.")
['steve', 'isn', 't', 'at', 'the', 'office', '']
```

So you could do some work here to pick a better regular expression, but you'll need to decide how you want to handle text like `steve isn't at the 'the office'`.

So to select the right solution for you, you'll have to think about what input you'll get and what output you want.

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly,

you should do this:

```
User_Input_list = User_input.split(' ')
```

and that's it...

Answer (score 0):

```
User_input = raw_input("Please enter a search criterion: ")
User_Input_list = User_input.split(" ")
```

see:

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html

Answer (score 0):

Do the following

```
User_input = raw_input("Please enter a search criterion: ")
```

`User_Input_list = User_input.split()`

Answer (score 0):

You found re already, there is a nice example of splitting a string:

```
re.split('\W+', 'Words, words, words.')
```

Like this you get all words, all punctuation removed.